# Scala / Spray: Return all rejections as JSON

Tags: json, scala, spray

I'm writing a JSON API using Spray 1.2.1 and I would like to return all HTTP Responses in the following format by default.

`{
"type":"error",
"status":404,
"message":"Not Found"
}`

My own custom rejections / exceptions will have less generic content in the 'message' field, but I'm looking for a way of globally formatting (and possibly otherwise decorating, for debug/testing) all non-2xx responses.

Is this possible without handling every possible rejection and status code?

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: This mailing list thread contains a link to another way of generation json error responses: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/spray-user/UXoVj7YRdks/discussion

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is generic enough for you but here's how I do something similar:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

case class Rejection(type:String, status: Int, message: String)

object RejectionJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol{
   implicit val rejectionFormat = jsonFormat3(Rejection)
}
```

Then you can complete your routes with a Rejection, possibly in your RouteExceptionHandler like this:

```
trait RouteExceptionHandlers extends HttpService {

  import RejectionJsonProtocol._

  implicit def routeExceptionHandler(implicit log: LoggingContext) = ExceptionHandler {
    case e: UnsuccessfulResponseException =>
      requestUri { uri =>
        complete(e.response.status, Rejection("error",e.response.status,"Not found"))
      }
  }
    //other exceptions go here
}
```

Comment: FYI, intellij gave out to me for using a case class member called 'type', probably a reserved word.

Comment: @byrnedo You should escape the `type` identifier using backticks so that Scala treats it as a name instead of a keyword

Comment: Thanks for the tip @acjay